# How to make std::vector from other vector with specific filter?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, objective-c++

I have a `std::vector` filled with objects. I want to filter and copy all the elements for which some predicate returns `true` in to a new `std::vector`.

I've looked at `find` and `search` functions but they only return iterators.

I'm using *ObjC++* so I can use block functions as well as functors, if it helps. Can't use C++11 functions though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have C++11 then use `std::copy_if` as suggested in Eugen's answer. Otherwise, you can use [std::remove_copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) with appropriate modifications to your predicate's logic.

Comment: @Protheus "remove_copy_if" isn't exactly intuitive, so it is easy to miss. Fortunately C++11 finally gives us `copy_if`.

Answer (score 14):

you can use the std::copy_if method. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: Ah, so it is finally there in C++11! I was going to suggest a hand-rolled implementation à la http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2001/01/8022.php.